# Как правильно построить scalable app node.js

Tags: node.js, шаблоны-проектирования

Прочитал книжку Addy Osmani (google engineer) [Large-Scale JavaScript Application Architecture](https://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/) в ней описывается три паттерна: [mediator](https://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/#mediatorpattern), [Facade](https://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/#facadepattern), [module](https://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/#modpattern). Нет опыта построения большого приложения на node стоит ли использовать этот принцип? Или есть что-то более применимое под node? Возможно примеры реализации, или дока что-бы понимать в каком направлении двигатся

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Паттерны перечисленные Вами являются китами программирования и даже если бы Вы не прочли эту книгу и вообще не знали эти названия, то все равно применяли бы их в повседневной работе.
Назначение фасада, сокрытие логики, так же как и модуля, который ещё предоставляет публичный интерфейс. Медиатор позволяет работать с множеством других объектов создавая иллюзию конкретного объекта.

Чтобы создать приложение соответствующее времени, нужно знать очень много и возможно `node` не лучший выбор для освоения серверной части, так как информации на мой взгляд по ней ещё очень мало.

И чтобы хоть как-то добавить конкретики в ответ предложу поискать и почитать ответы на этом ресурсе по тегам - `mvc`, `mvp`, `solid`, `yagni`, `dry`, `kiss`, `reactive programming`, `domain driven design`.

Этого будет вполне достаточно чтобы ответить на большую часть Ваших вопросов.

И чтобы все из перечисленного правильно улеглось в сознании, нужно помнить что правильно спроектированное приложение должно быть похоже на гардероб педантичной модницы, в котором элементы упорядочены не только по принадлежности к типу, но и по необходимости и важности наряда.

Если сказать простыми словами, то -

1. инициализация всего приложения должна всегда происходить в одном месте. вы должны забыть что пишите код и начать писать инструкцию, открыв которую в следующий раз Вы сможете увидеть все связи и зависимости.
2. создайте единую точку получения всех зависимостей. Можно использовать все тот же фасад. Смысл в том чтобы не думать откуда что-то взялось.
3. не смешивайте логику, создавайте объекты отвечающих за свой логический участок приложения. Полюбите событийную модель.
4. всегда проверяйте передаваемые данные и выкидывайте исключения, чтобы быстрее находить проблемные места.
5. и самое главное для масштабируемых приложений - всегда помнить о низкой связанности и вовремя производить декомпозицию - использовать агрегацию.